# Prime number checker using Java

Tags: java

I am just a beginner in Java. I have tried to build a prime number checker using what I already know. I have used a method that finds the square root of the given number and then divides the number with all the integers less than that root and if in any one case answer is "0" then the number is not a prime; otherwise, it is.

---

My program works well with integer data type upto no.2147483647 but after this number for each and every number it gives the same output like --> "Yes!! The number is a prime number". Because of this I've tried using double data type but the result is still the same! For every number after 2147483647 it says it is a prime number.

---

**Question**: after using `Math.floor()` and `double` to store a bigger rounded off number, when I print my `ArrayList` it shows element "0" in it, but the in final result condition `if (contains(0) == true )` is bypassed and `if ( contains (0) == false )` is implemented for numbers greater than 2147483647

---

First Code using the `Integer` data type:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UltimatePrime {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int mod;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = (int) input.nextDouble(); //separate and get only integer part from the input 

        if (number >= 2 && number < 2147483647) //2147483647 is the limit for data type Integer
        {
            int j = (int) Math.sqrt(number); //get the integer square root of the input and assign it to j
            ArrayList modStorage = new ArrayList();
            for (; j>1; j--)
            {
                mod = number % j;  //divide the number with all numbers less than or equal to j
                modStorage.add(mod); //store all modulus or remainder operator results in ArrayList modStorage
            }
                if (modStorage.contains(0) == true) //if ArrayList modStorage contains 0 remainder than result = true
                {
                    System.out.println("Sorry" + ", " + number + " " + "is not a prime number.");
                }
                if (modStorage.contains(0) == false) //if ArrayList modStorage doesn't contain 0 remainder than result = false
                {
                    System.out.println("Yes!!" + " " + number + " " + "is a prime number.");
                }
            }

        else if ( number == 1) //special case for number 1
        {
            System.out.println("A prime number has only two factors: 1 and itself."
                    + "\nA composite number has more than two factors."
                    + "\nThe number 1 is neither prime nor composite.");
        }

        else //insuarace :D
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter proper number!");
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

---

Second Code using `double`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FinalPrime {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        double mod;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double number = input.nextDouble(); //separate and get only integer part from the input 
        number = Math.floor(number);
        if (number >= 2) 
            {
                double j = Math.sqrt(number); //get the integer square root of the input and assign it to j
                j = Math.floor(j);
                ArrayList modStorage = new ArrayList();
                for (; j>1; j--)
                {
                    mod = number % j;  //divide the number with all numbers less than or equal to j
                    modStorage.add(mod); //store all modulus or remainder operator results in ArrayList modStorage
                }
                if (modStorage.contains(0) == true) //if ArrayList modStorage contains 0 remainder than result = true
                {
                    System.out.printf("%.0f \n",number);
                    System.out.println("Sorry" + ", " + "it is not a prime number.");
                }
                if (modStorage.contains(0) == false) //if ArrayList modStorage doesn't contain 0 remainder than result = false
                {
                    System.out.printf("%.0f \n",number);
                    System.out.println("Yes!!" + ", " + "it is a prime number.");
                }
            }

        else if ( number == 1) //special case for number 1
            {
                System.out.println("A prime number has only two factors: 1 and itself."
                                + "\nA composite number has more than two factors."
                                + "\nThe number 1 is neither prime nor composite.");
            }

        else //insuarace :D
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter proper number!");
            }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use long or BigInteger if you require your method to work for large numbers.

Comment: If my answer below has helped you, please mark it solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `int overflow`. `2147483647` is the maximum value for `int`. This data type can't store larger numbers.

Double should be used for floating numbers.

For using big integers use `BigInteger` class which is `java.math` class. This class can store infinitely large numbers as long as you have enough memory on your machine.

**EDIT:**

As You are interested in understanding how `BigInteger` works I decided to edit my answer and introduce you to the world of `BigInteger`s. First of all let my assure: do You understand, that `double` isn't type for larger integers? In case it would be enough you can use `long` which is the type for integers larger than `int`.

In case `long` isn't big enough you should try `BigInteger`s. For huge `float`s there is `BigDecimal` class. Let's focus on `BigInteger`s.

**BigInteger**

`BigInteger` class has three `public static` fields of `BigInteger`s: `ONE`, `TEN` and `ZERO`. In case you want to check if a `BigInteger` equals 0 (yes, `BigInteger` can also contain small integers) it's definitely better to compare it to `BigInteger.ZERO` than creating new object `BigInteger(0)`.

**Construction**

What about constructors? There are three most commonly used. The first one takes `String` as a parameter, the second takes a `String` and an `int` radix (base of numeric system) and the third one takes bit array.

The last way that I use to construct `BigIntegers` is a `public static` method called `valueOf()` which takes `long` or `int` as a parameter.

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("1024"); // creates BigInteger representing number 1024.
BigInteger b = new BigInteger(1024); //also creates BigInteger representing number 1024.
BigInteger c = new BigInteger("10000000000", 2); //also creates BigInteger representing 1024
```

**Operations**

To check if `BigInteger a` equals `BigInteger b` just type

```
if (a.equals(b)) {...}
```

To add two `BigInteger`s `a,b` type

```
 BigInteger c = a.add(b);
 //or
 a = a.add(b);
```

Feel free to read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) which is great! Anyway, If You have any questions feel free to ask in the comment section. I'll respond until Sunday evening.

Comment: thank you for the reply.I am still not sure how to use Scanner and BigInteger together. Well what my question is that after using double to store bigger rounded off integers when I print my ArrayList it shows element "0" in it.But the in final result condition if (contains(0) == true ) is by passed and if ( contains (0) == false ) is implemented for numbers greater than 2147483647.

Comment: Edited. Hopeful will help you!

Comment: I don't know how it happened but in my second code with double I just changed if (contains( 0 ) == true ) with if (contains( 0.0 ) == true) and it worked !! Now my computer is giving me limit for testing bigger numbers :D Anyway I have decided to learn about BigIntegers ! thank you all for your help! Speially xenteros for introducing me to BigIntegers  :)