# I am trying to make a Prime Factorization Java code for my AP Computer Science class and I am stuck

Tags: java

```
public boolean checkPrime( int number )
{
    int divisor = 2;
    int remainder = 1; 
    while(number != divisor)
    {
        remainder = number % divisor ;
        if( remainder == 0)
        {
            return false ;
        }
        else
        {
            divisor ++ ;
        }

    }
    return true ;  
}


public void primeFactors ( int num )
{
    int i = 2 ;
    while(  i <= num)

    {

        if( num % i == 0)
        {
            boolean isPrime = checkPrime( i );
            checkPrime( i ) ;
            if( isPrime )
            {
                System.out.print("," + i);
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i++ ;
        }
    }
}
```

}

The issue I am having is I can not get it to print out more than jsut one of each number. For example if you input 16 it will only give you one 2 and not 4 2's. I am using check prime because my professor is making us, I know you can do the program without it. I am new on here and I greatly appreciate any advice!

Comment: A few advices: read [ask]. use a debugger. drink lots of water.

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38541142/prime-number-checker-using-java and a lot of duplicates about primes. Here you're making a lot of mistakes, like looping until number instead of sqrt(number), not dividing by the factor when you find it, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue I am having is I can not get it to print out more than jsut one of each number.

That's because of that `i++;` after the printing. Rather than moving on to the next potential divisor, you should stay on the same one until divisibility goes away.

Instead of incrementing the divisor, you should divide it out from `num`. For example, if you see that `num=24` is divisible by `2`, print `2`, and make `num=12`. The next iteration will print `2` again, and make `num=6`. The following iteration will print `2` for the last time, and make `num=3`. This is when your algorithm can move on to the next divisor, and print `3`.

Comment: Thank you very much