# Data exceeds the length of a "long"

Tags: java, android

Question: Person A gives Person B $1 in the first day, and the amount is doubled everyday. How much does Person B get after 100 days?

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

long x = 1;
int y = 1;
for(int p = 1; p <= 100; p++){
String o = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(x);
System.out.println("Day " + y + " gets " + o);
x = x * 2;
y = y + 1:
}
```

Output:

```
Day 1 gets 1
Day 2 gets 2
Day 3 gets 4
Day 4 gets 8
Day 5 gets 16
Day 6 gets 32
Day 7 gets 64
Day 8 gets 128
Day 9 gets 256
Day 10 gets 512
Day 11 gets 1,024
Day 12 gets 2,048
Day 13 gets 4,096
Day 14 gets 8,192
Day 15 gets 16,384
Day 16 gets 32,768
Day 17 gets 65,536
Day 18 gets 131,072
Day 19 gets 262,144
Day 20 gets 524,288
Day 21 gets 1,048,576
Day 22 gets 2,097,152
Day 23 gets 4,194,304
Day 24 gets 8,388,608
Day 25 gets 16,777,216
Day 26 gets 33,554,432
Day 27 gets 67,108,864
Day 28 gets 134,217,728
Day 29 gets 268,435,456
Day 30 gets 536,870,912
Day 31 gets 1,073,741,824
Day 32 gets 2,147,483,648
Day 33 gets 4,294,967,296
Day 34 gets 8,589,934,592
Day 35 gets 17,179,869,184
Day 36 gets 34,359,738,368
Day 37 gets 68,719,476,736
Day 38 gets 137,438,953,472
Day 39 gets 274,877,906,944
Day 40 gets 549,755,813,888
Day 41 gets 1,099,511,627,776
Day 42 gets 2,199,023,255,552
Day 43 gets 4,398,046,511,104
Day 44 gets 8,796,093,022,208
Day 45 gets 17,592,186,044,416
Day 46 gets 35,184,372,088,832
Day 47 gets 70,368,744,177,664
Day 48 gets 140,737,488,355,328
Day 49 gets 281,474,976,710,656
Day 50 gets 562,949,953,421,312
Day 51 gets 1,125,899,906,842,624
Day 52 gets 2,251,799,813,685,248
Day 53 gets 4,503,599,627,370,496
Day 54 gets 9,007,199,254,740,992
Day 55 gets 18,014,398,509,481,984
Day 56 gets 36,028,797,018,963,968
Day 57 gets 72,057,594,037,927,936
Day 58 gets 144,115,188,075,855,872
Day 59 gets 288,230,376,151,711,744
Day 60 gets 576,460,752,303,423,488
Day 61 gets 1,152,921,504,606,846,976
Day 62 gets 2,305,843,009,213,693,952
Day 63 gets 4,611,686,018,427,387,904
Day 64 gets -9,223,372,036,854,775,808
Day 65 gets 0
Day 66 gets 0
Day 67 gets 0
Day 68 gets 0
Day 69 gets 0
Day 70 gets 0
Day 71 gets 0
Day 72 gets 0
Day 73 gets 0
Day 74 gets 0
Day 75 gets 0
Day 76 gets 0
Day 77 gets 0
Day 78 gets 0
Day 79 gets 0
Day 80 gets 0
Day 81 gets 0
Day 82 gets 0
Day 83 gets 0
Day 84 gets 0
Day 85 gets 0
Day 86 gets 0
Day 87 gets 0
Day 88 gets 0
Day 89 gets 0
Day 90 gets 0
Day 91 gets 0
Day 92 gets 0
Day 93 gets 0
Day 94 gets 0
Day 95 gets 0
Day 96 gets 0
Day 97 gets 0
Day 98 gets 0
Day 99 gets 0
Day 100 gets 0
```

---

You can see that in day 64 the number becomes negative and after day 64 the number becomes 0.

How can I get the amount in day 100? "long" is the largest data type I know.

Comment: Of course similar questions have been asked before. See for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38541218/5772882).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to switch over to using Java's BigInteger class.

Here's some documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Essentially, BigInteger can hold numbers larger than a register on your CPU can fit - which would be longer than a long.

Also, you don't need to keep track of y, since its value will always be the same as that of p.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class MyClass 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    BigInteger x = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2L);
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();

    for(int p = 1; p <= 100; p++)
    {
      String o = nf.format(x);
      System.out.println("Day " + p + " gets " + o);
      x = x.multiply(two);
    }

  }
}
```

Note: for multiplying by 2, `x.shiftLeft(1)` is more efficient than `x.multiply(two)`. You may wish to consider replacing `x = x.multiply(...)` with `x = x.shiftLeft(1);`.

Comment: what is `y` for?

Comment: I kept y since it was in OP's example. I've removed it now.

Comment: @ScaryWombat It's backup of `p`, just in case. Redundancy is required when handling $1267650600228229401496703205376 (it's a lot of money).

Comment: Is that shift left just an efficiency measure? It feels like it makes the answer less general, what if it was multiple by three

Comment: It's partly an efficiency measure... I'll swap it over to multiply though, just to keep things general.

Comment: @Andreas Sarcasm is duly noted, but again - it was there for consistency with the original example. It's gone now.

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be humor, not sarcasm. Anyway, talking about efficiency, it would likely be better to use `BigInteger.ONE` instead of `new BigInteger("1")`, and `BigInteger.valueOf(2L)` instead of `new BigInteger("2")`, and to only do `BigInteger.valueOf(2L)` once outside the loop. [`valueOf(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf-long-) uses constants for values `-16` to `16`.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger day64 = new BigInteger(whatever the number);
BigIneger day65 = day64.add(day64);
```

Smth like that.

You can edit the code to fit the loop and not have to type it out each day.